# Заполнение объектов в промежутке

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

появился вопрос касательно three js, имеется вот такой вот навес: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача заключается в том, чтобы в промежутке между началом и концом по длине навеса, заполнить промежутки столбами с определëнным шагом, который можно менять (input), то же самое и с длиной (input). Как это возможно решить?

P.s. столбы моделенные, GLTFloader

код:

```
var width = parseFloat(document.getElementById("x_pos_id_1").value);
    var height = parseFloat(document.getElementById("x_pos_id_3").value);
    var length = parseFloat(document.getElementById("x_pos_id_5").value);
    var xOffset = parseFloat(document.getElementById("x_pos_id_7").value);

    var score_of_stolb = width/xOffset;

    for(var i = 0; i < score_of_stolb; i++){
      scene.remove(arr[i]);
      arr.splice(i, 1);

      //alert('remove');
    };
    

    //initial offset so does not start in middle.
    for(var i = 0; i < score_of_stolb; i++){

      
      var mesh  = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      mesh.position.x = i * xOffset;
      arr.push(mesh);
      scene.add(mesh);
    };
```

весь код реализуется по нажатию на кнопку*

Comment: Непонятно в чем тут проблема? Берете промежуток, высчитываете сколько в нем столбов, располагаете там столько столбов ..

Comment: @Kromster окей, допустим у нас есть цикл, который заполняет расстояние столбами в зависимости от шага, ВОПРОС, как сделать динамическое изменение кол-ва столбов в цикле for(var i = 0, i < count_of_stolb, i++){
      scene.add(object);
      arr.push[object];
}

Comment: Ну как.. Вот у вас должен быть код типа `ПостроитьНавес(int ширина, высота, count_of_stolb, итп)`, вот вы в нем все считаете и расставляете. При изменении конфигурации (изменили число столбов или ширину), дергаете `УдалитьНавес` + `ПостроитьНавес`. Вот вам и динамика и инкапсуляция.

Comment: @Kromster весьма неплохая идея, сейчас попробую, я просто как изначально планировал, динамияески всë изменяит по oninput, но потом влетел в тупик с изменением кол-ва столбов, т.к. его нельзя было пихнуть внутрь, ибо он бы бесконечно добавлял бы объекты по каждому изменению

Comment: Для MVP (minimal viable product) - Удалить+Построить самое простое и быстрое с т.з. реализации. Дальше, если все ок, то уже можно будет прикручивать кеширование, транзишены и прочие плюшки.

Comment: @Kromster чекни пж код, я не вдупляю, что не так, он отказывается удалять элементы со сцены+массива, вроде всё норм, но оно не работает...(код внёс в правки вопроса)

Comment: Почему не просто что-то типа "для всех объектов в arr - удалить их из сцены"? А вы зачем-то считаете новое количество столбов и иго начинаете убирать ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

код оказался на деле весьма простым, имеется длина, её делим на шаг столба, далее подставляем это значение в цикл под ограничение цикла. А если хотим удалить всё, просто берём и релоадаем страницу, либо отдельно канвас, чтобы сбросить все добавленные элементы на 3Д холст.